# How do I get the last element of a CMake list of unknown length?

Tags: list, cmake

I have a list of unknown length containing strings.  I want to compare the last item with the second to last item, but I can't find an easy way to retrieve these elements so I can compare them.

I tried getting the length of the list and then using (length-1) as the index I pass into the list `GET` function, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
set(my_list a b c) # I don't actually know the length of the original list
list(LENGTH my_list list_len)
list(GET my_list (list_len-1) last_item) # doesn't work
```

I expect to have element `c` saved in the `last_item` variable, but it remains empty.  What is the right way to do this in CMake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use [`math`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/math.html) in order to perform mathematical operations.

```
list(LENGTH my_list list_len)
math(EXPR list_last "${list_len} - 1")
list(GET my_list ${list_last} last_item)
```

---

*Edit*: It is possible to get elements from the end of a list using negative numbers, you can use -1 to get the last item of a list:

```
list(GET my_list -1 last_item)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  I tried both of these options and they worked well. Thanks!

Comment: This needs to be documented. When looking up list(GET there is nothing about this even though it's such a common need for me.